# Get rid of non-digits and then get last n chars of a string in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, string, linq

I have two tables, both of them with a **Phone** column.

This column -NVARCHAR(30)- can have its stored data formatted in several different ways, from **0001 222 333 444** to **222 333 444** to **(0001)-222333444** to **-** to even an empty string.

I would like to do a query using LINQ where the first three examples shown above would give a match, so I need to get rid of everything that's not a number and then get the last 9 digits out of the string. However, I haven't been able to do this using just one query, and instead I'm looping through each of my results and apply the phone number filters there. Any way this could be done with just the query?

Answer (score 3):

`String` is essentially an `IEnumerable<char>`, so what you can do is:

```
var digits = s.Where(char.IsDigit);
```

Now, there's no real elegant way to take the last 9 digits: `IEnumerable<>` implies that there's no way to find out its length other than to iterate over it. What I can suggest is:

```
var digits = new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).Reverse().Take(9).Reverse().ToArray());
```

Or you can get all fancy and write your own `TakeLast()` extension method:

```
public static IList<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int n)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>(n);

    foreach(var item in enumerable)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        if(queue.Count > n)
            queue.Dequeue();
    }

    return queue.ToList();
}
```

Which will greatly simplify your code:

```
var digits = new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).TakeLast(9).ToArray());
```

Comment: Using _Reverse()_ or _ToArray()_ throws an exception _"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method XXX"_ I already had tried something similar, and that's why I ended up having to put all my filter logic in a separate loop.

Comment: @etc2702 You will have to pull the data out from SQL Server and do the transformations inmemory.

Comment: A well-placed ToList() or similar usually pulls the data and enables fancier processing w/o throwing the exception above.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jonesopolis' answer, you can do the following to get the last N characters from a string:

```
var str = "0001 222 333 444";
var n = 9;

var result = string.Concat(str.Where(char.IsDigit).Skip(str.Length - n).Take(n));
```

this will skip the first few characters and pull back the last `n` number of characters. You may need to do a test on string length to make sure the string contains sufficient characters - I've not tested this so if the string is too short it might throw an error.

Comment: I was taking this approach too, to find the shortest answer.  Doesn't quite work though - after you remove the non-digits, str is not the same length as before.

Comment: @Jonesopolis guess the string needs to be parsed to remove all non-numeric characters and then do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an EntityFramework mapped class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

and an EF context that contains

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons
```

You can filter using something like

```
var ppl = context.Persons.Where(x => x.Phone.Replace(" ", "").EndsWith("222333444")).ToList();
```

This will produce SQL that looks like the following, satisfying your request for a filtering solution.

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone]
FROM [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
WHERE REPLACE([Extent1].[Phone], N' ', N'') LIKE N'%222333444'
```

Then any formatting can be applied in a middle tier /  model builder / automapper style solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of Regex & LINQ :

```
Regex r1 = new Regex("[^0-9.]");
Regex r2 = new Regex("(.{9})$");
var Last9Digits = PhoneNumbers.Select(PhoneNo => r2.Match(r1.Replace(PhoneNo, "")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the last N characters of a string.
/// </summary>
public static string GetLast(this string source, int numberOfChars)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) || numberOfChars >= source.Length)
        return source;

    return source.Substring(source.Length - numberOfChars);
}
```